# add page x of y in single custom post type - wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I've been trying to create a custom pagination in my custom post single.php 
 I tried to use this code but it doesnt work

```
<?php
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
echo 'Page ' . $paged . ' of ' . $wp_query->max_num_pages . ' pages';
?>

<?php previous_post_link('%link', '<span class="prev"><</span>'); ?>
<?php next_post_link('%link', '<span class="next">></span>'); ?>
```

do i need to query my post first so the number of pages that will show is just the post that i have in my custom post type??

Comment: https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-paginate/

Comment: ^ Why use a plugin for something so trivial?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this one

```
    <?php if ( get_query_var('paged') ) { $paged = get_query_var('paged'); } else if ( get_query_var('page') ) {$paged = get_query_var('page'); } else {$paged = 1; } ?>

<?php previous_post_link('%link', '<span class="prev"><</span>'); ?>
<?php next_post_link('%link', '<span class="next">></span>'); ?>
```

Thanks

Comment: no luck :( doesnt show the count post on my custom post type